# Text input shifts text down 1px

Tags: css, cross-browser

A `div` and an `input type="text"` with identical CSS styling position their contents differently. The `input` has the text 1px lower on Firefox, Chrome and Safari (on macOS at least).

Try clicking <kbd>toggle</kbd> in the snippet below for an example. Notice that the elements are positioned the same, just the text within shifts by 1px.

As it's consistently offset across browsers, I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing. How can I reliably avoid this 1px shift?

```js
const button = document.getElementById('toggle');

const a = document.getElementById('a');
const b = document.getElementById('b');

let state = false;
toggle();

button.onclick = toggle;

function toggle() {
  a.style.display = state ? 'none' : '';
  b.style.display = state ? '' : 'none';
  state = !state;
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}

input,
div {
  position: absolute;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  appearance: none;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  width: 200px;
  height: 22px;
  font: inherit;
  line-height: 21px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle">toggle</button>

<input type="text" value="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" id="a" />
<div id="b">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</div>
```

And on JsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/afhjm4pu/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical centering in the `input` is less effected by the `line-height` (the text is vertically centered). However, the `height: 22px` and the `line-height: 21px` cause the text to be centered differently in the `div`. Change the line height to `22px`.

**Note:** I've added a red right border to the div to show that the items are still toggled.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('toggle');

const a = document.getElementById('a');
const b = document.getElementById('b');

let state = false;
toggle();

button.onclick = toggle;

function toggle() {
  a.style.display = state ? 'none' : '';
  b.style.display = state ? '' : 'none';
  state = !state;
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}

input,
div {
  position: absolute;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  appearance: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 22px;
  font: inherit;
  line-height: 22px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #eee;
}

div {
  border-right: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle">toggle</button>

<input type="text" value="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" id="a" />
<div id="b">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</div>
```